# Turn on iTunes EQ via AppleScript

Tags: itunes, applescript

Can I turn the iTunes EQ on/off using AppleScript?

I found a way to change the preset, but not turn the EQ on or off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an iTunes Equalizer ON-OFF Script that toggles, so you can turn on/off just with the call of one script

```
tell application "iTunes"
    if EQ enabled is false then
        set EQ enabled to true
    else if EQ enabled is true then
        set EQ enabled to false
    end if
end tell
```